# Method call terminates in between and jumps to the next method call

Tags: android, methods, execution, sequential

I'm trying to build a notepad application in android. I'm in this situation, when the user chooses to create a new file while still working on a file, the application should first ask for a save and then restart the MainActivity to create the new file.

So, basically, the sequence is as follows:

->Working on current file
->Clicks on New File
->Save dialog
->Restart MainActivity.

For this, I've been using a method called new file as below:

```
public void new_file()
    {
        save_file();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

The problem here is that, everytime I run the application and text this part of the code, the dialog pops up and immediately a new file.

I would like to know how I can first let the Activity finish the save_file() method call and then the Activity Restarts.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it works fine, but not seeing safe_file() code (BTW: consider switching to more standard function naming convention) it's hard to be sure , but note dialogs are **asynchronous**, so you cannot start dialog and expect all further code to wait for dialog dismiss. I assume you popup dialog in safe_file() method, so you should either call back to start new activity from there when done saving or you should do that in your dialog click listener.

Comment: Right! There's the glitch in my code then. Yes, I'm using a dialog in the save_file().
Well, I can't start new activity from the save_file(), since I don't have to do it every time I save the file, so, I'll have to think of an alternative.
Anyways, I didn't know that dialogs are asynchronous so, now that I do, I'll have to think of an alternative.

Comment: If your dialog listeners are in activity's inner class, then just call your activity method back from there.

Comment: My Activity Listeners are in my MainActivity itself.
MainActivity -> save_file() -> listeners

Comment: If i get you right, then this should work: user hit "new" you call new_file(), it then calls save_file(), then save_file(), well... saves and then it calls jump_to_main_activity().

Comment: You're right on target about that except that I don't have a method called jump_to_main_activity(), i just restart the main activity

Comment: But actually, I tried calling a method to restart an activity and it WORKS! Thanks a lot mate :D

Comment: I knew, it was just to show the flow, not the exact code. Glad you got that working.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Negative](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.html#BUTTON_NEGATIVE), [Positive](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.html#BUTTON_POSITIVE) and [Neutral](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.html#BUTTON_NEUTRAL) buttons of the AlertDialog mechanism to detect when a user has exited the dialog. Then, use an OnClickListener to decide which button was clicked, and only restart the Activity then. Something like:

1. Show dialog
2. Wait for one of the buttons to be clicked
3. Restart activity when a button is clicked, as that means the user is exiting the dialog.

Comment: Since I need a text field to enter the filename, I'm using a custom dialog, I didn't think I could still use the Negative, Positive and Neutral buttons. Is it possible?

Comment: You can use the AlertDialog to take input as well. I've done it before.

Comment: Yep, just found that out. Anyways, that isn't the problem. Since, dialogs are asynchronous, whatever dialogs i use, I'll fall into the same pit again. I'll have to find an alternative.

Comment: Not really. If you remove the code to relaunch the main activity from new_file() into one of the onClickListeners(), it'll only execute when the button it clicked. Therefore, the save file dialog's exit will be the only way to restart the activity.

Comment: Well, that'll actually revoke the user's convenience to create a new file.

Comment: How so? When the user clicks new file, you can prompt him/her to save the existing one, and when he/she clicks the save button on the dialog, restart the activity.

Comment: There is also a case that the user might click on the save file button which calls the same save_file() and the user gets the same dialog where he has to enter the filename and click save file button on the dialog and he gets a new file although, he wasn't calling for a new file

Comment: You can use a flag like NEW_FILE_AFTER_SAVE to determine whether or not to launch the activity again.

Comment: Something just worked out with this issue for now.
But, your flag idea sounds good too, will try that out as well. Thanks a lot man :D